# Нужен ли отдельный абзац для этого предложения?

Tags: типы-ошибок

(1)Как-то раз мы с друзьями решили пойти на рыбалку.
(2)С утра мы взяли удочки, накопали червей и достали из гаража палатку. После этого все свои вещи мы сложили в машину и отправились к заболоченному краю деревни.

Текст написал ребенок. Он сомневается, нужно ли писать второе предложение с красной строки. Текст повествовательный, а он вроде бы предполагает наличие вводной части, то есть первого предложения.

Comment: я бы написал вместо "решили пойти" - "пошли". "Пошли" - это не обязательно ногами куда-то, а значит, что задумали, стали собираться, собрались и ушли на рыбалку(но не обязательно, что дошли). Собрались пойти - это не по-русски, это рунглиш. Так что смущает скорее всего именно этот момент. Абзацев никаких не нужно. Можно переставить слова: удочки собрали, червей накопали, палатку из гаража достали... И "я с друзьями", "я и мои друзья".

Comment: Как-то раз мы с друзьями решили пойти - стали гуглить, куда бы нам пойти, решили, что на рыбалку, стали гуглить рыбные места, затем какой стафф нам понадобиться для фишинга, для кемпинга... Собрались пойти - лишний глагол, собрались порыбачить, собрались в поход. Собрались пойти в поход - криво...

Comment: почему не надо абзаца?

Comment: Если писать вступление, то нужно писать не про рыбалку: Погода стояла прекрасная! Лето в самом разгаре, зелень, жара... Поэтому я с друзьями решили отправиться порыбачить. - Тогда можно было бы выделить абзац, потому что "про погоду". А тут это некое псевдорешение ни к чему не привязанное. С чего его выделять в отдельный абзац?

Comment: Абзац должен содержать какую-то мысль. Какая мысль в этом одном предложении? Вывод есть, мысли нет.

Comment: То есть абзац должен содержать в себе какую-то мысль, тему, может контраст настроений. Если это акцент на "решили", значит должно быть содержание связанное с решением: почему решили, как решили, когда решили? А тут всего этого нет, проще слепить все в одно и назвать "сборы на рыбалку" - это если план составлять. То есть одно предложение с выводом или оценкой, но без содержания, не тянет на отельный абзац. Либо его нужно доработать и присоединить к основной части, либо расширить до отдельной мысли.

Comment: Иначе получается бессвязный текст: мы решили/мы собрались/мы пошли/ мы пришли/ мы ловим... Должны быть абзацы, но со своим содержанием, а предложения выводы - это сцепки внутри абзацев и между абзацами, переходы между ними. Но само такое предложение не самодостаточное, поэтому одно единственное предложение редко выделяю в абзац. Для абзаца важно содержание - хоть друзей назвать описать, хоть погоду, а не сцепка-вывод, сцепки не достаточно. Занудно получилось) но как смог.

Comment: Выводы часто одним предложением формулируются: эта поездка мне очень понравилась, я рада, что была там!

Comment: Не достаточно писать: мы подумали, мы решили, нам было весело, у нас получилось. Выводы, впечатления должны иметь основание, нельзя оторвать впечатление от содержания.
Это очень слабые бессодержательные тексты получаются. Шаблонные, возможно, прокатывают в ЕГЭ, не знаю точно, на троечку мб, на отвали. Нужно описывать, аргументировать, возможно, и только потом делать вывод, оценку. "эта поездка мне очень понравилась, я рада, что была там!" - бессодержательный шаблон, извините.

Comment: Это как блюдо на столе, которое стоит для заполнения пространства и создания видимости наполнения, но которое никто не ест, потому что оно несъедобное. Но увы, гостям нужно что-то есть, как и тем, кто читает тексты. 2 предложение неплохое, 3 тоже "отправились к заболоченному краю деревни" - хорошо, а первое - кривое, если его еще в абзац выделить, то вообще не понятно зачем.

Comment: Обозначить решение пойти - 1 абзац. Поч нет?

Comment: Содержания нет. Как понять "обозначение решения пойти" - лозунг что ли? Причина какая? Каким образом обозначено, какой знак, почему, от чего, зачем? Пусто.

Comment: Смотрите, я придумал: мысль - это вопрос; тема, содержание - ответ на вопрос. Какой вопрос можно задать к первому абзацу-предложению?

Comment: "С чего все началось".

Comment: Началось *всё* с того, что "Как-то раз мы с друзьями решили пойти на рыбалку." - тогда не ясно, что такое "всё"? Получается рассказ вообще не про рыбалку, и рыбалку и сборы на неё нет смысла разделять, потому что это *всё*, видимо, будет уточнено, случится далее. Но тогда оправдано "решили пойти", потому что видимо не дошли), а случилось *всё*. Что *всё*, что случилось-то?